# load_workbook giving value error for string literal

Tags: openpyxl

So I am writing a simple test code in python, but I cant seem to load my workbook to read and write into. The workbook I am trying to open has a lot of data and is linked to an Access Database. I am also using Python 2.7.

Here is the code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
print("here1")
wb = load_workbook("Z:\\PythonFiles\\testexcel2.xlsx")
print("here2")
ws1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name("Output Model")
import datetime
print("here3")

ws1.cell(row=3, column=9).value="Somevalue2"

wb.save("Z:\\PythonFiles\\testexcel2.xlsx")
```

Now here is the error:

```
here1

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Z:\PythonFiles\Test.py", line 4, in <module>
wb = load_workbook("Z:\\PythonFiles\\testexcel2.xlsx")

File "C:\Python27\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 233, in load_workbook
parser.parse()

File "C:\Python27\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 104, in parse
dispatcher[tag_name](element)

File "C:\Python27\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 235, in parse_row_dimensions
self.parse_cell(cell)
File "C:\Python27\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 191, in parse_cell
value = _cast_number(value)

File "C:\Python27\openpyxl\reader\worksheet.py", line 55, in _cast_number
return int(value)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1E-3'
```

Comment: Sounds like a possible bug. Could you submit a bug report with a sample file?

FWIW the connection with the database will be lost.

Comment: I submitted the bug report. The code works fine with work books that are not the one I am trying to open. I am not sure why that particular workbook doesn't work with the code, but it is really annoying :(

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the code which has been fixed. https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/commits/8cc875b206b08895a1a0ae9ac33cb997a941eddf